# How does pervasive map xml data?

Tags: xml, pervasive

I need to map xml data using pervasive map designer. I will be mapped into txt file. I always get error "Since multiple source record exist, no records will be written". Are there any solution to solve it ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend spending some time in the Pervasive Help documentation, (it's actually very good).  Here's the article on the XML connector:  http://docs.pervasive.com/products/integration/di/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=connectors/XML_connector.html

I used to work with Pervasive Data Integrator quite a bit, and I remember XML sources being a bit tricky to set up sometimes.  The thing to keep in mind is that the connector is attempting to convert your XML file into rows of data, so you'll want to tweak your connector settings such that it sees the rows of data the way that you expect.

Comment: Please give us some extracts of your source and target files so we can help you better.  I have spent two years using this tool, and though I hate it, I would be happy to help you!